# Why is my function to hide image not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick, hide

My code was working properly until I decided to make a small change, and I guess I accidentally deleted something because my console is saying hide image is not defined at decrement when I already defined hide image. I can't find my error everything worked fine :'(. I went over my hide image function and it seems like everything is correct. When I load it on html the error seems to appear when a user does not make a selection is runs the function decrement, so when time reaches zero it displays an image with the correct answer, and it used to clear it out and display the next question with the available choices, but now it just stays on the if time = 0 screen and doesn't move on to the next question.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    //set up object-array for questions
    var trivia = [
        {
            question: "On Drake & Josh, what's Megan favorite phrase?'",
            choices: ["Boobz", "Idiots", "Oh, really?", "Damn! Where are my 
    apples?"],
            rightChoice: 0,
            image: "assets/images/boobs.gif",
            background: "<img src='assets/images/90back.jpg'>"
        },
        {
            question: "What color lipstick does Spongebob use when he kisses 
    Mr. Krabs fake Millionth dollar?",
            choices: ["Magenta", "Stardust", "Coral Blue #Oof", "Blorange"],
            rightChoice: 2,
            image: "assets/images/spongebob-coral-blue.gif",
            background: "<img src='assets/images/90cart.jpg'>"
        },
        {
            question: "What thottie accessory was popular in the 90's, that 
    is currently popular today?",
            choices: ["chokers", "bandaids", "airpods", "tidepods"],
            rightChoice: 0,
            image: "assets/images/chokers.gif",
            background: "<img src='assets/images/90back.jpg'>"
        },
        {
            question: "During sleepovers, Mystery Date allowed girls to date 
    which sexy actor?",
            choices: ["Port", "James Franco", "Paul Rudd", "Chris Evans, Mr. 
    America"],
            rightChoice: 3,
            image: "assets/images/chris-evans.gif",
            background: "<img src='assets/images/90cart.jpg'>"
        },
        {
            question: "What was the SPICIEST band in the 90's?",
            choices: ["Madonna", "Hillary Clinton", "BackStreet Boyz", "The 
    Spice Girls"],
            rightChoice: 3,
            image: "assets/images/zig-a-zig-ha.gif",
            background: "<img src='assets/images/90back.jpg'>"
        }
    ];
    var rightAnswer = 0;
    var wrongAnswer = 0;
    var unansweredCount = 0;
    var time = 15;
    var intervalId;
    var userSelection = "";
    var selected = false;
    var running = false;
    var totalCount = trivia.length;
    var chosenOne;
    var triviaRand;
    var newArray = [];
    var placeHolder = [];

    //hide resetBtn until called
    $("#resetBtn").hide();
    //click startBtn button to start game
    $("#startBtn").on("click", function () {
        $(this).hide();

        displayTrivia();
        runTime();
        for (var i = 0; i < trivia.length; i++) {
            placeHolder.push(trivia[i]);
        };

    })
    //time: run
    function runTime() {
        if (!running) {
            intervalId = setInterval(decrement, 1000);
            running = true;
        }
    }
    //time--
    function decrement() {
        $("#timeLeft").html("<h4> Madonna, we're running out of time  " 
    + time + " </h4>");
        time--;

        //stop time if reach 0
        if (time === 0) {
            unansweredCount++;
            stop();
            $("#choicesDiv").html("<p>Oh no! You ran out of time . The 
    correct choice is: " + chosenOne.choices[chosenOne.rightChoice] + " 
   </p>");
            hideimage();
        }
    }

    //time stop
    function stop() {
        running = false;
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
   play question and loop though and display possible answers
    function displayTrivia() {
        //generate random triviaRand in array
        triviaRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * trivia.length);
        //console.log(triviaRand);
        chosenOne = trivia[triviaRand];
        console.log(chosenOne);

        $("#questionDiv").html("<h2>" + chosenOne.question + "</h2>");
        for (var i = 0; i < chosenOne.choices.length; i++) {
            var newUserChoice = $("<div>");
            newUserChoice.addClass("answerChoices");
            newUserChoice.html(chosenOne.choices[i]);
            //assign array position to it so can check rightChoice
            newUserChoice.attr("userChoices", i);
            $("#choicesDiv").append(newUserChoice);
        }

        //click function to select rightChoice
        $(".answerChoices").click(function () {
            //parseInt() function parses a string argument and returns an 
    integer of the specified radix
            //locate array based on userChoice
            userSelection = parseInt($(this).attr("userChoices"));
            console.log(userSelection);
            if (userSelection === chosenOne.rightChoice) {
                console.log(chosenOne.choices[chosenOne.rightChoice]);
                stop();
                selected = true;
                rightAnswer++;
                userSelection = "";
                $("#choicesDiv").html("<p>Damn, boi ‍</p>");
                hideimage();
                console.log(rightAnswer);
            } else {
                stop();
                selected = true;
                wrongAnswer++;
                userSelection = "";
                $("#choicesDiv").html("<p>That is incorrect! The correct 
    choice is: " + chosenOne.choices[chosenOne.rightChoice] + "</p>");
                hideimage();
                console.log(wrongAnswer);
            }
        })

        function hideimage() {
            $("#choicesDiv").append("<img src=" + chosenOne.image + ">");
            newArray.push(chosenOne);
            trivia.splice(triviaRand, 1);

            var hideimg = setTimeout(function () {
                $("#choicesDiv").empty();
                time = 15;

                //run the score screen if all questions answered
                if ((wrongAnswer + rightAnswer + unansweredCount) === 
    totalCount) {
                    //clearbck();
                    $("#questionDiv").empty();
                    $("#questionDiv").html("<h3> Game Over!  Let's see 
    your score : </h3>");
                    $("#choicesDiv").append("<h4>  Correct: " + 
    rightAnswer + "</h4>");
                    $("#choicesDiv").append("<h4>  Incorrect: " + 
    wrongAnswer + "</h4>");
                    $("#choicesDiv").append("<h4>  Unanswered: " + 
    unansweredCount + "</h4>");
                    $("#resetBtn").show();
                    rightAnswer = 0;
                    wrongAnswer = 0;
                    unansweredCount = 0;

                } else {
                    runTime();
                    displayTrivia();

                }
            }, 2000);


        }

        $("#resetBtn").on("click", function () {
            $(this).hide();
            $("#choicesDiv").empty();
            $("#questionDiv").empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < placeHolder.length; i++) {
                trivia.push(placeHolder[i]);
            }
            runTime();
            displayTrivia();

        })

    }
    })`
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a syntax error correction! You should use single or double quotation in src attribute of img tag in hideimage function:

```
$("#choicesDiv").append("<img src=' " + chosenOne.image + " '>");
```

Comment: I already tried that but the error is still there once the timer runs out it will display “Oh no! You ran out of time . The correct choice is: The Spice Girls” for example and it will stay there instead of displaying a new question after about 2 seconds

Comment: @JuanPimentel Can't see what the 'chosenOne' var is there for. Lose it. choices[rightChoice] should work